# Error: change in schema version between compile time and run time - SQLNCLI11

Tags: sql-server-2012

This is a head scratcher. I've searched the forums and no one has been able to answer this. Not even GilaMonster on SQLServerCentral has chimed in on this one! One user suggested that it may be referring to a schema version number however it seems to be a bit high of a number for that. I looked for a query that could verify this but wasn't able to find a query to return version number of a schema, only the id of a schema.

The error below (message_id 7359) showed up recently and briefly on our servers that are linked. I'm not looking for a why so much as a what. What datatype is used for the compile time and run time values in this error message and is there a function already for formatting that into something human readable, assuming it is a datetime value? I've got a hunch its relatively new since there's nothing out there, that I could find anyway, that explains what those digits are.

Here's an example of the message we get:

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SSQLS01" reported a change in schema version
>   between compile time ("186839690094804") and run time ("186852574981615") for table ""SS017"."dbo"."TVHA"".

Thank you !

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575975/ole-db-provider-for-linked-server-reported-a-change-in-schema-version-error

Answer (score 1):

As described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143259/what-is-the-internal-representation-of-datetime-in-sql-server, SQL stores datetime values as an 8-byte field.

The compile time in your sample error, 186839690094804, when converted to hex, is 0x0000A9EE015BA8D4. The date part is 0x0000A9EE, and the time part is 0x015BA8D4. 0x0000A9EE, when converted back to decimal, is 43502, and using an epoch of 01 January 1900, that comes out to 06 February 2019.

The date part of the run time in your sample comes out to 09 February 2019. Those pass the sanity check.